# Is it normal for my laptop to randomly hit 100% CPU?

Tags: laptop, cpu, overheating, hp-laptop

I have a HP 14-CF2000 laptop. Every so often (every 30 minutes or so if I have just left the home screen on, a bit longer if I'm in a meeting/browsing) or upon waking up from sleep/startup my CPU will hit 100% and the temperatures will skyrocket (usually to 75°C-85°C). The high CPU usage is shown on Task Manager to be caused by Windows Update, Antimalware Service Executable, HP JumpStarts and wsappx. It usually only lasts a minute before going back to 2-40% (depending on what I'm doing) and 25-50°C. **Is this a sign of something wrong? Will this damage my laptop?** It's only 3 months old and has had the fan replaced a few weeks ago.

Comment: No this is pretty common. CPUs generate heat in a very small area, and do so extremely quickly. that the temperature resumes a normal level almost as quickly indicates that your cooling is working, if less-than-aggressively (I hate that about laptops). Your system should shut down before you exceed max temp for your CPU. If you are really worried about it, you can reduce your maximum frequency in your power management settings, which will cause your CPU to pause ever few clock ticks and do nothing for a cycle, which does reduce power draw and thus heat accumulation.

Comment: @FrankThomas Okay great, it's not a big worry just a bit annoying that the fans kick right up, would rather that than a dead brick of a laptop though. Once I start going to lectures I might do that because I'll only be typing up notes.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal for the CPU on Windows to hit 100% every so often due to background tasks such as ones that help keep the system maintained. It will always hit 100% briefly when waking from sleep/hibernate and there will always be high CPU usage for a minute or so after startup as background applications and services fully start up. It's fine for the CPU temperature to hit 80°C occasionally as long as it stays below 90°.

It's not a sign of sign of something wrong and shouldn't damage the laptop. It will shut off if it overheats and reaches a critical temperature to prevent damage.

Comment: Modern laptops have such power design that basically any temperatures below CPU's Tjunction are acceptable. That would be 100°C for most models, even 105°C for some. It actually makes sense - if you throttle the CPU below its Tjunction, you're leaving some performance on the table.

Comment: Okay great, thank you. My performance never goes down so I assume all is good? just never saw this on my old laptop because I didn't look at the temperatures and the fan was noisy so I don't know anything about this.

Comment: @gronostaj so as long as it isn't getting close to the Tjunction (think it's 100°C for mine) it's safe? Anything to worry about in terms of heat damage to components?

Comment: @ClumsyWithTech The cooler the better. The CPU itself shouldn't care much, but some components around it could suffer if they're not cooled properly and that depends on laptop manufacturer's design. But as long as you're not running it at 100% constantly it should be fine. There's not much you can do about it in a new-ish laptop.

Comment: @gronostaj so  30-50°C average should be alright?

Comment: @ClumsyWithTech Yes, that's perfectly normal